# how to specify what's considered an error, so that I can get squiggly lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, squiggly

I'm programming in C, and often times I see myself forgetting to type the '&' when using `scanf`. I've used [replit](https://replit.com) in the past and there, in that case the variable gets a squiggly underline showing it's wrong. Is there any way I could configure this in VS Code, in other words, can I specify what's considered an error?

Answer (score 0):

Add the C/C++ extension from Microsoft. It will add IntelliSense

Use this link to learn how to add extensions: [LINK](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace)

Use this link to read about customizing IntelliSense for your needs: [LINK](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense)
(unless it already does what you need)

Comment: Thanx man, but I'm using this extension already. I have absolutely no clue how to customize IntelliSense for that need. If you could give me some guidance.